# How to connect a female connector to HDMI Cable?

Tags: hdmi, cable, connector

I am trying to connect a Legrand Wall Socket female connector to a HDMI Cable.

It as that socket has a pin outs on (in total 19 pin outs) which we will have to punch that cable It has Total 19 Pin outs:

[image]

How ever we will have to cut the HDMI Cable and connect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given color codes for HDMI Cables, with the Ethernet and without the Ethernet. I have two different HDMI Cables for which colour codes are different. I have specified those cables below as "*Type A*" and "*Type B*"

1) Blow is the "*Type A*" of a cable that I have. for witch I have given the color codes for the Ethernet and without the Ethernet. in two different Images.
[image]

[image]

2) This is a color code for "*Type B*", How ever for this type of cable there is only one color code that is for with the Ethernet, But this color code works well for both type of cables with and without the Ethernet.

[image]

Comment: The information in the second image is incorrect. Group E consists of pins 14, 17 and 19, the three contacts required for Ethernet functionality and they are not ungrouped as you said, but grouped into a differential pair with separate shield just like Groups A, B, C and D.

Answer (score 5):

Did you already go out and purchase this wall plate?  If you did not already buy it, then do NOT purchase that wall plate.  Instead, purchase one like [this one](http://www.jack2rack.com/hdmi-products/hdmi-av-wall-plates/1-hdmi-wall-plate-90-degree-white.html), as it has an HDMI socket on each side.  No wiring.  Of course, this still makes me wonder about why you only have one wall plate.

You should be using two wall sockets... the whole purpose of using wall sockets is for a professional installation, and if you are using only one, you kind of defeat that purpose.

But... you want wiring and pinout diagams...
[image]

[image]

..of course, you could just use two wall plates, and just be consistent between them.  The reason why this is going to be difficult?

> There is no standard for color-coding the wires and it can become very easy to make a mistake.  I think it’s fair to say that you will have a tough time contacting the manufacturer to find the color code for the wiring.

But this article on [repairing damaged HDMI cables](http://www.blueechosolutions.com/info/hd-ez-lock/repairing-damaged-hdmi-cable/) might come in handy.

In the end... just getting [wall plates that don't need to be wired](http://www.jack2rack.com/hdmi-products/hdmi-av-wall-plates/1-hdmi-wall-plate-90-degree-white.html) might be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is not the correct color coding thou, It helped me to find the right color coding. I have pasted it in the answer below.

Comment: That's great that you find your color coding, but as I said in my answer, there is no color coding standard right now for HDMI cabling.  So, you are lucky you found yours.  Good job!

Comment: thanks at lot! here is the colour coding that can be used for HDMI

Comment: Concur. Just buy male-to-male HDMI cable (with a jacket suitable for in-wall use), already wired, and run that in the walls. You are buying into a world of hurt by attempting this. I can't imagine that this kludge would meet HDMI specs.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was connecting this Legrand Wall Socket to a HDMI cable and found this topic. After I cut the cable I was surprised of how different cable color schemes can be. I differently would run into some trouble while doing this with Legrand's instruction. I like @BonGart answer

> There is no standard for color-coding the wires and it can become very
>   easy to make a mistake.

That is true. The only possible solution is to carefully brake hdmi connector from the unused side of your cable and see how pinout is organised. Example: I had +5v on blue wire, while in the Legrand's instruction +5v cable was red. At least Legrand's numbering shame matches pin numbering, meaning HDMI pin 18 goes to hole 18.

Answer (score 0):

Different manufacturers use different colours on the ungrouped strands.
Some older versions only have 14 or 15 strands and not 19, each shielded packet only has the data '+' and '-' pair not the 3rd uninsulated wire.
If replacing broken plug, I would change both ends and rewire according to the Version type standard.
The industry doesn't like DIY HDMI connections, That is why for a kit, you can pay £300 plus.
Still the Chinese are opening up this market.
Obviously the faster the signal rates the more they are affected by DIY repair jobs, in saying that unless you are a AV buff, you probably wouldn't notice.
It is OK to have millions of changing pixels but if your eyes only have 
the equivalent of 10's of thousands sat 4M from the picture, it can become a gimmick.

Comment: Consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state.